# python threads exits immediately

Tags: python

I am new to python.

I am trying out `Hbase thrift client using thrift`. I got some code on net, which I just modify to work with latest version of `thrift` but when I run the code , it just exit, no threads are started.

Here is the code.

```
import json, traceback, sys, datetime, time, logging, threading, random
import logging.handlers

import thrift
sys.path.append('gen-py')


from thrift.transport.TSocket import TSocket
from thrift.transport.TTransport import TBufferedTransport
from thrift.protocol import TBinaryProtocol
from hbase import THBaseService



gWritenItems = 0
gStartT = 0
gEndT = 0

recordsPerBatch = 300 #reports per client per day
columns = 3

#config
concurrent = 10
records = 60000#6000000 #6 million
bytesPerRecord = 1024



mylock = threading.RLock()
class writeThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadname, RecordsThreadwillwrite):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name = threadname)
        bytesPerColumn = int(bytesPerRecord/columns) - 11 #suppose 3 columns

        self.columnvalue = "value_" + "x"*bytesPerColumn + "_endv"
        self.tbwBatch = int (RecordsThreadwillwrite / recordsPerBatch)

        self.transport = TBufferedTransport(TSocket('pnq-adongrevm1', 5151), 40960)
        self.transport.open()
        protocol = TBinaryProtocol.TBinaryProtocol(self.transport)

        self.client = THBaseService.Client(protocol)
        self.table = "example"

    def run(self):
        print "+%s start" % (self.getName())
        global gEndT
        global gWritenItems           

        threadWritenItem = 0
        for loopidx in xrange(0, self.tbwBatch):            
            self.write_hbase() #write                                           
            threadWritenItem += recordsPerBatch   

        mylock.acquire()
        gEndT = time.time()  
        gWritenItems += threadWritenItem
        print "%s done, %s seconds past, %d reocrds saved" % (self.getName(), gEndT-gStartT, gWritenItems)
        mylock.release()
        self.transport.close()                   

    def write_hbase(self): #write 50 rowkyes, and  3 column families in each rowkey
        print self.getName(), "Start write"
        batchmutations = []
        for i in xrange(0, recordsPerBatch): # write to db, 300 items together
            mutations = []
            rowkey = "RK_%s_%s" % (random.random(), time.time())       
            for ii in xrange(0, columns):
                mutations.append(THBaseService.TPut(row=rowkey, columnValues=[TColumnValue(family="f1", qualifier="%s"%ii, value=self.columnvalue)]))
        self.client.putMultiple(self.table,mutations)        



itemsPerThread = int(records / concurrent)
for threadid in xrange(0, concurrent):    
    gStartT = time.time()
    t = writeThread("Thread_%s" % threadid, itemsPerThread)
    t.start();
print "%d thread created, each thread will write %d records" % (concurrent, itemsPerThread)
```

I just get a message `10 thread created, each thread will write 6000 records`

Comment: Move the print statement inside the `for` and `join()` the threads outside of it

Answer (score 2):

Yep, this is because you are not waiting for threads to finish their job, so the main thread just exits. Try this:

```
itemsPerThread = int(records / concurrent)
threads = []
for threadid in xrange(0, concurrent):    
    gStartT = time.time()
    t = writeThread("Thread_%s" % threadid, itemsPerThread)
    t.start();
    threads.append(t)

# wait until all finish the job
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

**EDIT** Ha, I don't think I'm right here, because you didn't mark your threads as daemons. It should work even without joining. But have a look at this code:

```
class CustomThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        print "test"

for x in xrange(0, 10):
    t = CustomThread()
    t.start()
```

It will always reach `print "test"` line no matter what. So in your code it should always reach `print "+%s start" % (self.getName())` no matter what. Are you sure it doesn't work? :)

If it doesn't, then there are only two possibilities:

1. There is a blocking operation and/or exception in your `__init__` method. But then it would not reach final print;
2. `concurrent` variable is `0` for some reason (which is not consistent with the final print).

Comment: +1, the quid here is that the main thread is the one that determines the program's lifespan. You have to keep it alive.

Comment: @Avinash Is that so? I can't see other issues to be honest.

Comment: The `print` is outside the `for`

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn Yeah, but how is that related to threads not working?

Comment: Oh I'm just as lost, I thought by "doesn't work" he meant he only got one print line instead of `n`

Comment: your code is working and getting print statement but my run is not getting executed